# What is the best way to save an image in MongoDB using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, image

I'm developing a JS system with Node server and need to save images in MongoDB in a way that saves as much space as possible, and I'm currently converting the image to String base64 and saving as an attribute of a document in the collection.

However, with few photos (Full HD, 4K, 8K) the DB was already 350MB in size, it was something around 15 photos.

Besides this method there is another one in which the image is uploaded to a server folder and only the path and name of the image are saved.

I want to save server space because it will be deployed to the Google Cloud Platform, and I do not want to have extra costs just because of photos.

My question is: What methods other than those mentioned above exist to save an image in MongoDB as efficiently as possible ??

Note: I can not post the code because I have it only on the company computer

Comment: If you are interested in another way besides using computer data, I use an image host like imgur and make use of their API. In my apps I use the api to programatically upload my images to their host and then store the URL as the data

Comment: I appreciate the help, I have not thought about it yet, it's a good idea